# calling python __init__ on a class

Tags: python

I have a class (say called Account) saved a as a variable (say cur_class) and I want to initialize an instance of the class. I thought

```
cur_class.__init__()
```

would work but it is giving me 'unbound method **init**() must be called with Account instance as first argument (got nothing instead)'. Obviously I'm doing something wrong - can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks,
Richard

Comment: Why do this?  It's done automatically when you do `our_class()`.

Comment: @S.Lott - I'm not big on python and didn't realise you could simply add some brackets after a variable name to instantiate. It's not that common in langauges.

Comment: @Richard: "It's not that common in langauges" Please don't assume things and impose other language syntax on Python.  It will lead to more confusion and more strange and difficult to answer questions. A tutorial will save you a lot of time.

Comment: @S.Lott - I don't think the question was strange or difficult to answer. I'd searched through python documentation for about half an hour before asking this. If you have any good tutorials, please feel free to recommend.

Comment: @Richard: I asked for clarification specifically because the question was strange and difficult to answer.  I'm sure you thought your question was perfect.  There are hundreds of Python tutorials.  Indeed, there's one right on the Python web site.  You can use "search" on the Stack Overflow site to see all the times the "Python Tutorial" question has been asked and read all of the answers.  It's a common question.

Comment: @Richard, note that you should probably call it `CurClass`, as [Python naming convention](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) says that `cur_class` (lower case with underscores) should be used for variable names.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try `cur_class()`. For example:

```
In [1]: class C(object): pass
   ...: 

In [2]: cur_class = C

In [3]: obj = cur_class()

In [4]: obj
Out[4]: <__main__.C object at 0x1953c50>
```

A slightly longer explanation is that [Python classes are callable](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#callable). Calling a class returns a new instance.